# Angular 2 manage Route's state change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Basically, I have 2 routes:

```
{ path: ':id', component: VideosListComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/0', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

In the app **route root** I'm listing videos through `VideosListComponent`. After video clicked I need to **display video** and **prevent change Router state** so the Component will not reinitialized.

But when I use routes like this:

```
{ path: '', component: VideosListComponent },   
{ path: ':id', component: VideosListComponent }
```

when `:id` changes Router state changes also.

**First solution** works, but I don't like that my app root redirects to `/0`.

**QUESTION**: Is it possible to achieve changing route from `/` to `/:id` won't change Router state?

---

**SOLUTION**
I've got it to work according to @admax . I made **parent** and **child** route. From my parent `VideoList` Component I moved all `showPlayer` functionality to `Child PlayerComponent`. It fells like a right way to do in Angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variant should work for you:

```
{ path: '', component: VideosListComponent },   
{ path: ':id', component: VideosListComponent }
```

> when :id changes Router state changes also.

Router state will change, but the component instance will be reused, because both routes declared to use the same component type, so the component state will be preserved. You just need to react on params change and actualize the state according to it.

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    if (params['id']) {
       // display video
    } else {
       // display list
    }
});
```

One more suggestion: if the videos list must be presented on both "pages", maybe it just should be moved to the parent route?

```
{ 
    path: '', 
    component: VideosListComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', component: SomeEmptyComponent },
        { path: ':id', component: VideoDetailsComponent }
    ]
}
```

Comment: maybe you didn't understand. On videoList item click I need to preserve videoList (without changing) and show Video player depending on ``:id``. When I use your solution ``getVideos`` function executes every time I click on VideoList item

Comment: @lomboboo it's probably because you are calling getVideos at the wrong place.

Comment: I like your idea with child route, I'll try in a minute

Comment: it seems that it will work. So if I understand correctly I should move my ``showPlayer`` functionality to ``VideoDetailsComponent``?

Comment: @lomboboo yes, exactly

Comment: I wanted ``reply`` to you directly, but ``@`` doesn't work =\. I will try implement your solution, but it would take some time. Then I'll accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: can I use ``VideoPlayer`` Component as child within other components like ``SearchList`` or ``TagList``?